# How to tell web browser opened - socket, how much bytes i will send to it

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Pre history:
I send to opened by my client by web browser - socket, packets with encrypted (html page - payload ) by my vpn.
Client receives packets, and before Windows can process them, catches this packets ( using Pydivert) and decrypts payload, and sends it back to Windows network stack. But web browser is not  loading the page.
So, I tried to send some more data after the real page data, and page was loaded, but with this new added data, that was sent after real page.

I'm assuming that web browser gets the page, but waits for more data.

**So, what I'm asking is - How to tell client, that I will send exact amount of bytes?**

Comment: HTTP already does this.

Comment: @user253751 yeah, i know, but because of that i send it as "encrypted" data, and then as "decrypted" data, HTTP gets amount of bytes wrong;p

Comment: no it doesn't. You encrypt the amount of bytes that HTTP sends, then you decrypt the amount of bytes that HTTP sends too

Comment: @user253751 Okay, but then, what could be a problem? i just cant figure it out, like , i send a page to the socket, but web browser don`t want to output this page, i explained what i tried, if you need more info about the code, i can add it.

Comment: Well what is the program doing when it hangs? Is it calling `read` and waiting for more data? (probably) Then what is your VPN program doing? Does your VPN program have data that it hasn't returned yet?

Comment: @user253751 Not the program hangs, hangs the web browser ( google chrome ). I send to socket ( that was opened by google chrome ) - html page using socket connection ( from VPN servet to VPN client) and before Client windows can process this packet, i intercept this packet, and decrypt the payload, after i put this packet back to network stack, so windows can process it, so the web browser receives the page, but asks for more data ( as i found out ).

Comment: Obviously the packets you are decrypting are not the same as they were before you encrypted them. If they were the same, then the same thing would happen. Chrome couldn't tell the difference if the packets were the same.

Comment: @user253751 Actually, that was true, can you add answer, so i can close this topic?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer were in the header of http packet, as i was sending 1500 bytes , but in CONTENT-LENGTH was said that i will send 1505 bytes.